# Full text search in SQL 2005 excludes single digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I am using Full text search with SQL server 2005. Everything works fine except searching with one digit Keywords. For example search with '1' or '2' does not work but search with '12' works fine.

I am aware of the digits being the noise words. Is there a way to allow these digits search ?.

Will just removing these from the noise list fix the problem?

Any better ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, removing these from the noise list will fix the problem. It's not recommended though, be prepared to undo the changes you make to the file =-)

Just for you to know, the file is: ~/FTData/noiseeng.txt (noiseeng.txt is for great Britain . For US its noiseENU.txt) << Props to the comment below

If you upgrade to sql server 2008, you should note that noisewords were replaced by stopwords.

You can find further info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx

and here: http://arcanecode.com/2008/06/03/advanced-queries-for-using-sql-server-2008-full-text-search-stopwords-stoplists/

Comment: Thanks sir, I figured it out and FYI noiseeng.txt is for great Britain . For US its noiseENU.txt.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know. Sorry about that!